# How to make the Number view in keyboard UITextField to become default?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, uitextfield

I have a UITextField but my users will prefer enter some number in that field rather than typing text character (like enter a cost a product). So, how can I make the Number View in the keyboard to become default whenever the user tap into the UITextField?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In interface builder, just set the keyboard field of the UITextField to Number Pad.

Answer (score 0):

You can also do it in code as UITextField conforms to the UITextInputTraits protocol (where you can set the keyboardAppearance and many other things).